# How to define a range like this in excel?

Tags: excel

I saw someone posted a question with codes like this:

```
Range("VendorList[[Target Area]:[Product]]")
```

how can this range being generated at the first place?

it seems that [ and ] are not allowed, but how can the range above being referred to?

Comment: In the case above it is highly likely that `VendorList` is actually a table, and `Target Area` and `Product` are fields of that table. This kind of syntax is perfectly valid in formulas, but I haven't used it personally in actual range references in VBA (since there is a better way).

Comment: I think you're right on that! How can i close this question?

Comment: @Trowa - Don't close it. Put the answer in an mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Brandon, the range is actually referring to a Table named: VendorList and then for [Target Area] and [Product] are referring to its fields.